# Is there any promise that Dart Stream API must preserve the order of elements?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

I have a question about the contract on `Stream` API.

More specifically, I'm wondering why `Stream.asyncMap` is implemented not to break the order of elements in the stream.[[1]](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Stream/asyncMap.html)

I guess there can be some cases where the order of elements is not kept on `asyncMap`.
For example, if I pass an asynchronous function with HTTP communication to a server where the response latency has large variance, the events might happen in order of (1) HTTP req is sent for the 1st element (2) HTTP req is sent for the 2nd element (3) HTTP res is received for the 2nd element and sent to the downstream (4) HTTP res is received for the 1st element and sent to the downstream. In this case, the output stream will be ordered as [res2, res1] for the shortest latency as a whole.

However, in fact, the implementation is intend this order: (1) HTTP req is sent for the 1st element and pause the subscription (2) HTTP res is received, it is added to the downstream, and the subscription is resumed (3) HTTP req is sent for the 2nd element and (4) HTTP res is received and sent to the downstream.

So I want to know the intention of this implementation. I guess there might be an official contract that `Stream` API must not break the order, but I'm not sure.

Any insight will be helpful, thanks!

Comment: yes, it preserve the order, proof https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/b6f9dbc570c4e9065e922228c9747b4ea8104904/sdk/lib/async/stream.dart#L551 - most important is `if` at line `559`

Comment: @pskink Thank you for you comment. I've known the implementation preserves the order, but I'm wondering "why" it preserves the order: is there any good reason for it, such as the contract of the API?